# Printing from a file and storing in arrays.

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Im trying to read from a file into an array, which is shown in the first for loop. This part of my script works, however i want the answers that the user gives to be copied into the array q.a in the q structure. and the at the end of the script the questions and answers given printed off. Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working for me?

```
  struct qa{/
  char q[40][250];
  char a40][250];
  };

int main()
{
   int a, i, k, l, j;

   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("quest.txt", "r");

   struct qa q;

      for(i>0;i<=11;i++){
      fgets(q.q, 250, (FILE*)fp);
      printf("%s", q.q);
      scanf("%s", q.a[l][j]);
      }

      for (i=0;i<11;i++){
        strncpy(q.a[j], q.q[k], 250);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){    
        printf("%s/n", q.a[l][j]);
      }
```

I get a segmentation fault error when i try and run the script that only started happening when i put the strncpy for loop in.

Comment: 1. Why not check that `fopen` succeeds. 2. `fgets(q.q, 250, (FILE*)fp);` - Why the cast 3. Perhaps use more meaningful variable names

Comment: You never assign a value to `j`. And you should use variable names other than q, i, j, k etc. Give them real names such as "question", "answer" etc. It won't make the program correct, but at least it makes the program more readable, including to you.

Comment: fopen does work as i get the questions that are saved in the file its getting the programme to read them one by one and store the answers.

Comment: @Joepoint maybe it works now, but you should check anyway, `fopen` returns `NULL` if the file cannot be opened, then you should display some error message such as "cannot open file" and abort. But there are many other issues....

Comment: Ok i will do that. could you explain how i can write the answers given to the array?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you never initialize your values : i j k l are never initialized and a isn't even used.
Then you're trying with `scanf("%s", q.a[l][j]);` to put a char * into a char.
See stacktrace [image: StackTrace]
For debugging purposes install and use valgrind/gdb if you're into cli or any debuggers in your IDE, it will be easier
This is the code I used, if you want to know which lines point to which line of code
[image: Code]

Change `scanf("%s", q.a[l][j]);` to `scanf("%s", q.a[l]);` and do the same for the last printf

Also remember to compile with flags like -W -Wall -Wextra so that you can get more warnings from the compiler, it can detect most of your mistakes.[image: Compilation]

Answer (score 1):

This is awful:

```
  for(i>0;i<=11;i++){
  fgets(q.q, 250, (FILE*)fp);
  printf("%s", q.q);
  scanf("%s", q.a[l][j]);
  }
```

with one inconsistency per line!

`for(i>0;i<=11;i++)` the first element of a `for` is for *assignation* so it should never contain a comparison. You want `for(i=0; i<11; i++)`

`fgets(q.q, 250, (FILE*)fp);` - `q.q` is an array of char arrays, when what is expected by `fgets` is an array of *characters*. It should be `fgets(q.q[i], 250, (FILE*)fp);`.

`printf("%s", q.q);` invokes undefined behaviour, because `q.q` is an array of array of chars when `%s` expects a char pointer. It should be `printf("%s", q.q[i]);`

`scanf("%s", q.a[l][j]);` `%s` expects a pointer to an array of characters, and you give it the value of a single character! What you want is `scanf("%249s", q.a[i]);`

This means nothing:

```
  for (i=0;i<11;i++){
    strncpy(q.a[j], q.q[k], 250);
  }
```

`j` and `k` are uninitialized automatic variables, so their value is *anything*. In short you are writing random values at random memory location!

Even the last part is poor:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){    
    printf("%s/n", q.a[l][j]);
  }
```

`l` is still uninitialized, the end of line is `\n` with a backslash and not a straight slash, and `%s` still expects a char pointer... If you want to print the questions and answers, just do:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){    
    printf("%s\n%s\n\n", q.q[i], q.a[i]);
  }
```

it will give you the question on a line, the answer on the following one, and the empty line before next bloc.

TL/DR: you really should consider learning the basics of C language...